# Ubuntu installation stuck after first reboot on encryption password screen

Tags: boot, nvidia, password, encryption

I've just installed Ubuntu without any problem using normal installation.

My GPU is Nvidia and Ubuntu is installed on SSD. (I've another HDD)

Then I decided to try the encryption feature as shown below.

[image]

Unfortunately, right after the first reboot, it just stuck at the encryption password screen. (this is not my actual screenshot, the image was taken from https://linuxhint.com/encrypt_drive_ubuntu/.

The actual message on my screen after I entered the password is `cryptsetup (nvme0n1p3_crypt):set up successfully` and it just stuck there like forever.

[image]

If you need more info to solve this issue, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If it is saying that it set up the `crypt` successfully, then it's probably not the encryption that's broken, but the OS boot. There is likely a process not starting correctly, causing the system to hang. Press `Esc` or `F10` to see the verbose output of the OS booting after entering your key and getting the successfully unlocked message. The last process listed before the system stops doing anything, or any errors you might see at the end of startup, might be the cause. You may need recovery mode or a new install to fix it.